# Window contents disappear after maximizing

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, nvidia

Window contents usually disappear after Maximizing them! Especially Firefox. I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 on a [Vaio Z56](http://www.laptopspec.net/tag/vgn-z56/) laptop (graphics card: nVidia GeForce 9300M GS). I've read [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106738/maximizing-window-makes-content-disappear) before and do everything that was said in the answer but they didn't work for me.
(Something worse happen!!!My toolbar is disappeared!I have a terminal on Desktop and it's the only thing I can use.I can't access administration panel!)

Answer (score 0):

This has all the signs of a bug in the display driver. That [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106738/maximizing-window-makes-content-disappear/106748#106748) on Ask Ubuntu is on the right track. What you may be missing is that if you're currently using the free driver (`nouveau`), you may need to explicitly install the non-free driver (`nvidia`). On Ubuntu, there is a GUI for that: click the “restricted drivers” notification, or select “Additional Drivers” in the administration panel. See the [Nvidia binary driver howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia) for more information.

Comment: Something worse happen!!!My toolbar is disappeared!I have a terminal on Desktop and it's the only thing I can use.I can't access administration panel!